I have a 2 monitor set up, how do I have it so when I click an application on the 1st monitor it only pops up on the 1st monitor?
I have open Chrome tabs on both monitors then I work on other app. When I click the Chrome icon on dock (on the 1st monitor), is it possible that I can only let Chrome back to the top of screen on the first monitor. Now Chrome will back to the top of screen on both monitors.
I am not sure if it is possible. If possible it will be useful in the case like this: I write some code on my second screen and I need to check some info from Chrome, so I click Chrome icon on the dock. But Chrome will be on the top of my both monitor and covers my code app. So after I get my information, I need to click my code app again to bring it to the top.
If I can make Chrome on top of the first screen only , I can check both screens for the information I need to check.

The workaround I use now is to use safari to open my work-related pages, and put safari on the 2nd monitor.

If an app has multiple full screen windows (not just maximised but placed into macOS full screen), the last used full screen window will be switched to when clicking the app in the Dock. Therefore, given the following setup,











Primary Display
Desktop 1
VS Code active
Chrome last used


Secondary Display
Desktop 2 active
Chrome




clicking Chrome in the Dock will switch the primary display to Chrome and leave the secondary display on Desktop 2.
Therefore clicking VS Code and Chrome will continue to only switch the primary display. This happens until the last used Chrome (or active Chrome) is the one on the secondary display, i.e. by manually switching spaces on the secondary display to Chrome, then requiring manually switching spaces on the primary display.

So the key is to make vscode full screen in my second display, Then when I click chrome icon in dock in the first display, mac will only bring chrome to top on the first display. Was this what you said ?

If that is the case, which I already knew as the full screen app will always on the top, I was hoping there maybe other way to do it.
